# Name declaration for JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

```
JTextField tfA = new JTextField();
tfA.setName("tfB");
```

Now, What is my text field name?
`tfA` or `tfB` ?

Comment: I'd be suggest to use put/getClientProperty, you can to multiple this indentificator, note part of ClientProperty are implemented in API, but this is special commands with quite long desriptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is that the field name is tfB. The variable will be tfA.

Answer (score 2):

The variable will still be called `tfA`, but the text field's name will be `tfB`.  Objects neither know nor care what you call the variables used to reference them in your code...